# how to fixed this issue while integrate with firebase

Tags: flutter

```
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.2.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.2.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.2.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-1.3.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-8.1.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
                                                ^
1 warning
```

Comment: This is just a warning, not an error. Can be safely ignored.

Comment: Are your dependencies is latest version?

Comment: yes , all dependencies are latest.

Answer (score 1):

Two things helped me..

1. setting minSdkVersion=21 in app/build.gradle
2. running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in terminal

I hope it'll work for you.

Answer (score -1):

this is the library version problem.
firebase libraries are conflicting with each other.

cloud_firestore: any

By doing this, you will solve the problem, but this is not the solution.